# testing node.js using mocha and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am building an API that uses CouchDB as a backend and whilst building the backend library I want to create a function in a library to add a user account and return success or failure but the callbacks are causing problems.

After reading up on JS Promises I realised that these would solve my problems but I can't get them to work despite reading lots of tutorials.

Could you take a look at my code and help me understand why it won't work?

```
var request = require('request');
var md5 = require('MD5');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var Q = require('q');

exports.new_account = function(params) {
    console.log("\nNEW_ACCOUNT")
    params.password = md5(params.password);
    //console.log(params);
    var token = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    var record = {
        type:"user", 
        status:"pending", 
        token:token, 
        credentials:params
    };
    console.log(record);

    var uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/testdb/'+params.email;
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    request({method: 'PUT', uri:uri, body: JSON.stringify(record)}, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('performing request')
        var top = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(top);
        if (top.error == 'conflict') {
            console.log('the supplied email address already exists');
            deferred.reject('account exists!');
        }
        console.log('resolving request')
        deferred.resolve('account added.');
    })
    //var res = {status:"success", message:"Account created"};
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What does it say? How do you use the new_account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think the callback function of your request should look like this:

```
function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('performing request');
  var top = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(top);
  if (top.error == 'conflict') {
    console.log('the supplied email address already exists');
    deferred.reject('account exists!');
  } else {
    console.log('resolving request');
    deferred.resolve('account added.');
  }
})
```

That's because you can't call both `resolve` and `reject`. If `top.error == 'conflict'` this will be the case.

How do you use the return value of this function?

For testing you can use [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) with [chai](http://chaijs.com/) and [chai-as-promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised). Your test could look like this (with `chai` and `chai-as-promised` which are very helpfull):

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised"),
    assert;

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
assert = chai.assert;

describe('user', function () {
  describe('.new_account', function () {
    afterEach(function (done) {
      done();
    });

    it("status should be success", function () {
      var params = {name: "John Doe", email: "test@gmail.com", password: "p455w0rd"};
      var promise = user.new_account(params);
      var expectedResult = 'account added.';

      //the first time, the account should be created successfully.
      return assert.becomes(promise, expectedResult, 'account added.');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm using Mocha and Assert to handle testing. This is my test script: `describe('user', function() {
    describe('.new_account', function() {
        var params = {name:"John Doe", email:"test@gmail.com", password:"p455w0rd"};
        var res = user.new_account(params);
        console.log('TEST: '+res);
        it("status should be success", function() {
            //the first time, the account should be created successfully.
            assert.equal(res, 'account added.');
            done();
        })
    })`

Comment: This is the fail message I get: '1) user .new_account status should be success:
     AssertionError: {"promiseDispatch":"function (resolve, op, operands) {\n        var args = array_slice(arguments);\n        if (messages) {\n    == "account added."' The problem is I have no idea what I am looking at and why I get the error :-(

Comment: I've added a test example. After some research I started to use `chai` with `chai-as-promised` to test promises. It does what I expect it should do.

Comment: Thanks. I have integrated your solution and it works perfectly, will mark as answer.

Comment: When I try to add a second test (which should return 'account exists' I get an error. My code is:
    it("status should be 'account exists'", function () {
      var params = {name: "John Doe", email: "test@gmail.com", password: "p455w0rd"};
      var response = user.new_account(params);
      var expected = 'account exists';
      console.log('response: '+response);
      console.log('expected: '+expected);
      //If we try to add the account a second time it should fail.
      return assert.becomes(response, expected, 'account exists.');
    });

Comment: In that case you should use `assert.isRejected()` instead of `assert.becomes()´. (as documented at [link]http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised)